# Why Html.Hidden won't generate hidden fields with the same name but different value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to generate a hidden list, so I use hidden fields with same name, however Html.Hidden outputs the existing value instead of new one. So this code...

```
<% 
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductIds.Count; i++)
    { %>
<%: Html.Hidden("ProductIds", Model.ProductIds[i], new { id=""})%>
<br />
Iteration:<%:i %>
Guid:<%:Model.ProductIds[i]%>
<br />
<% } %>
```

generates this HTML

```
<input name="ProductIds" type="hidden" value="48906f4c-1719-43ab-9d7e-c336a71b8624">
<br>
Iteration:0
Guid:48906f4c-1719-43ab-9d7e-c336a71b8624
<br>
<input name="ProductIds" type="hidden" value="48906f4c-1719-43ab-9d7e-c336a71b8624">
<br>
Iteration:1
Guid:b4f01496-dddf-41f2-a05b-43392d779a44
<br>
```

Note how even though the ids are different, the generated hidden fields got the same value. Why is this happening, and is there any way to work this around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but an easy workaround is to just construct the html yourself:

```
<% 
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductIds.Count; i++)
    { %>
<input name="ProductIds" type="hidden" value="<%:Model.ProductIds[i]%>">
<br />
Iteration:<%:i %>
Guid:<%:Model.ProductIds[i]%>
<br />
<% } %>
```

Comment: Another solution I found is <%: Html.Hidden("ProductIds", null, new { id="", Value=Model.ProductIds[i]})%>

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of a hidden list or multiple hidden fields with the same name? Couldnt you make it a single hidden field with all the values?

Comment: Never trust hidden fields to be valid sneaky people will mess with them to break your site

Comment: 1)The purpose if it to have a list, so that when it is POSTed it would be properly mapped to a List<Guid> that I can use in my action. 2) I can make it a single field with all values but I don't like complicating things when a simpler way should be possible. 3) Do you realize you asked 2 questions as an answer? :D